# Troubles updating the Grub2 config file for Windows 7

Tags: centos, grub2

I'm trying to update the Grub2 config file on my CentOS 7 workstation, however, when I get to the part of running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` I get the error message:

> /etc/default/grub: line 3: 7: command not found

**OS:** 
CentOS 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

The program mentions clearly, there's an error in the grub configuration file `/etc/default/grub`. Correct it and run the command again. Also make sure the `os-prober` package is installed.